# AS3 Websocket Handshake

Tags: actionscript-3, websocket

I'm trying to build a AS3 socket server that can handshake with html5 websockets. I've base my code on this link https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17

This is what i have using the same values as the example in the link:

```
 import com.dynamicflash.util.Base64;
 import com.adobe.crypto.SHA1;    

function getKey():void{
var key:String = "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
key = SHA1.hash(key);   
key = Base64.encode(key);
trace(key);
    //traces YjM3YTRmMmNjMDYyNGYxNjkwZjY0NjA2Y2YzODU5NDViMmJlYzRlYQ==  instead of s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo="

}
```

Now the example states that the output should be :

Concretely, if as in the example above, |Sec-WebSocket-Key| header field had the value "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==", the server would concatenate the string "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" to form the string "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11".  The server would then take the SHA-1 hash of this, giving the value 0xb3 0x7a 0x4f 0x2c 0xc0 0x62 0x4f 0x16 0x90 0xf6 0x46 0x06 0xcf 0x38 0x59 0x45 0xb2 0xbe 0xc4 0xea.  This value is then base64-encoded (see Section 4 of [RFC4648]), to give the value "s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo="

Am i missing something ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a while since I've even read any ActionScript but shouldn't you replace

```
key = SHA1.hash(key);   
key = Base64.encode(key);
```

with

```
key = SHA1.hashToBase64(key);
```

?  The current code converts the sha1 hash (a byte array) into a string but its the original byte array you need to pass into the base64 encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is of any help:

https://github.com/childoftv/as3-websocket-server